# Method navigation/Usage finding in Laravel projects with NetBeans

Tags: php, laravel, netbeans

I often use *Ctrl+Click* on a method to navigate to its declaration, or *RClick* -> *Find Usages* to see all usages of it.

In Laravel you often define in strings which method shall be called. For instance:

```
Route::get('customer/{id}', 'CustomerController@customer');
```

I see no way to navigate to the method `customer` in the class `CustomerController` automatically here. *Find Usages* doesn't find this one either.
Is there any way to get it working?

Comment: In Route::get() method, all things are passed as method argument.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your question, `CustomController@customer` is a string. So you cannot click on this string to find out its usages.

However, you can still create a route name for your routes and check for those routes. You can use this route names in your controllers, views and even models.

So using route names would give you tremendous flexibility in development. Just change your method usage in `routes.php` and it will be reflected in all places.